# Version mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "6" [90047-181]?

Tags: java, database, h2

I am trying to connect h2 data base using java but it's throwing "Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Version mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "6" [90047-181]" exception.

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test","admin","admin");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from TEST");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
        stat.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a very old version of H2 on the server side. However, the error message is confusing, this I will have a look at.

Comment: Actually, it might really be a very old client and a recent server.

Comment: i have installed h2 database in my system and m trying to access it. Might be i had installed old version.It would great if you provide any link so that i can install latest version. thanks

Comment: The link is: [http://www.h2database.com](http://www.h2database.com)

Answer (score 1):

These version numbers could confuse, because it seems internal versions.
Solution here is to use correct version of driver.